# Error: gradle and gms google-services

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have those errors i dont know how can i fix them

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0. Searched in
>   the following locations:
>
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android
>   Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom
>
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android
>   Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar
>
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom
>
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar
>
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom
>
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar

Project build gradle is here.

```
buildscript { 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
      }
    }

     allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

       }
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
}
```

App build gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0+'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` why do you need a version grater than 3.0.1... and does it exists? Maybe it's a wrong copy and paste from google services? ;) Are you trying the preview version of AndroidStudio?

Comment: Just installed canary preview and the default project put: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha06'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the android plugin for gradle 3.2.0 (as stable release) **doesn't exist**.

Use:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```